# Why Animation.cancel() and View.clearAnimation() don't work in my case?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I don't see why this code doesn't work as expected. I want to cancel an animation. To test it I call to `setLoading(true);` who starts the animation and immediatly to `setLoading(false);` who cancels the animation.

Code to test it:

```
setLoading(true);
setLoading(false);
```

Here the code:

```
    private void setLoading(boolean loading) {
        if (loading) {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);
            animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "start"); // for debug
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "end"); // for debug
                    mButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
            mButton.startAnimation(animation);
            mLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "cancel"); // for debug
            mButton.getAnimation().cancel();
            mButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

fade_out.xml:

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:startOffset="300"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

The Logcat:

```
start
cancel
end
```

Expected result:

```
start
cancel
```

---

**Why `onAnimationEnd()` is called after an `Animation.cancel()` or `View.clearAnimation()` ?**

I tried using `Animation.cancel()`, using `View.clearAnimation()` and using both.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's working as intended, from Animatoin source code:

```
public void cancel() {
    if (mStarted && !mEnded) {
        fireAnimationEnd();
        mEnded = true;
        guard.close();
    }
    // Make sure we move the animation to the end
    mStartTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    mMore = mOneMoreTime = false;
}

private void fireAnimationEnd() {
    if (mListener != null) {
        if (mListenerHandler == null) mListener.onAnimationEnd(this);
        else mListenerHandler.postAtFrontOfQueue(mOnEnd);
    }
}
```

you can check if it was cancel this way from within onAnimationEnd

```
animation.getStartTime() == Long.MIN_VALUE
```

Animation actually has this method:

```
private boolean isCanceled() {
    return mStartTime == Long.MIN_VALUE;
}
```

but it's private. The time is different because inside `cancel()` you can see that the time get sets to `Long.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: Then How can I cancel the animation?? or I can check in onAnimationEnd() if the animation was cancelled?

Comment: It works. Could you recommend a better way? or explain why the StartTime is different when the animation was cancelled? Thanks

Comment: I can't think of a better way but I updated the answer, you can see why start time has that value